# Some problems with dropdowns in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have next example of implementing dropdowns.

```js
let isTouchScreen = {
    Android: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function () {
        return isTouchScreen.Android() || isTouchScreen.BlackBerry() || isTouchScreen.iOS() || isTouchScreen.Opera() || isTouchScreen.Windows();
    },
};

let body = document.querySelector('body');

if(isTouchScreen.any()) {
    body.classList.add('touch');

    link = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

    link.forEach(function(index) {
        index.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let arrow = index.nextElementSibling;
            let menu = arrow.nextElementSibling;
            arrow.classList.toggle('active');
            menu.classList.toggle('open');
        });
    });
} else {
    body.classList.add('mouse');
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: 0;
}

body
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;

    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu {
    background: #181818;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: #181818;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #a4a6a7;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: #cd412b;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu__list
{
    display: flex;
}

.sub-menu__list
{
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.sub-sub-menu__list
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;

    display: none;
}

.arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 20px;

    display: none;
    background: url('../images/select.svg');
    height: 8px;
    width: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow.active
{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

body.mouse .menu__list > li:hover .sub-menu__list
{
    display: block;
}

body.mouse .sub-menu__list > li:hover .sub-sub-menu__list
{
    display: block;
}

body.touch .sub-menu__list.open
{
    display: block;
}

body.touch .sub-sub-menu__list.open
{
    display: block;
}

body.touch .arrow
{
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px)
{
    .arrow {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu__list
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .sub-menu__list
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .sub-sub-menu__list
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__list">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="menu__link">First level</a>
                <span class="menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a>
                        <span class="sub-menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu__list">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">First level</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="menu__link">First level</a>
                <span class="menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a>
                        <span class="sub-menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu__list">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Third level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

The next following problems related to screens which with is less than 767px.

In browser when i hover on the links by mouse i can't actually to get to some of them (check snippet on screens less than 767px). And next problem when on the mobile mode i am clicking on the links which have dropdowns it is ok. But those who does not have a menu, when you click on them it gives an error in the console.

Comment: Why are you sniffing User-Agents.... and who is using a Blackberry today?

Comment: Also, your code won't work next year: all the major browser vendors [are going to freeze the `User-Agent` header](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html) entirely precisely because of problems caused by people who thinking sniffing User-Agent values is a good idea...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It is an old script of touchscreen function, so thats why. Actually i would like to do the same on screens less than 767px without that function. But tell me how.

Comment: @Dmitriy You don't need any JavaScript at all, just use `` `@media screen and (pointer: coarse) and (max-width: 767px)` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the `nextElementSibling` exists before trying to toggle its class.

```
link.forEach(function(index) {
  index.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let arrow = index.nextElementSibling;
    if (arrow) {
      arrow.classList.toggle('active');
      let menu = arrow.nextElementSibling;
      menu.classList.toggle('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay what's about first problem? And how actually to make script works on screens less than 767px, i mean to remove this useless function of checking what device is being used.

Comment: That's why you should only ask one question at a time. I don't know the answer to your other problem.

Comment: Responsive web sites usually replace their navigation bars with a hamburger menu on small screens to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah but here it doesnt matter becouse on screens less than 767 its already adaptive, i can actually easy integrate this to burger menu if it needs, but the problem when links lined up in vertical you can't get to some of them becouse of sub menu. Maybe the best way to solve it just by adding diplay block property to all of links.

Answer (score 0):

```js
link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

link.forEach(function(index) {
    index.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let arrow = index.nextElementSibling;
        if (arrow) {
            arrow.classList.toggle('active');
            let menu = arrow.nextElementSibling;
            menu.classList.toggle('open');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: 0;
}

body
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;

    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu {
    background: #181818;
}

.link {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: #181818;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #a4a6a7;
}

.link:hover {
    background: #cd412b;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li
{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu__list
{
    display: flex;
}

.sub-menu__list
{
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.sub-sub-menu__list
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;

    display: none;
}

.arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: none;
    background: url('../images/select.svg');
    height: 8px;
    width: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow.active
{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
    
    .menu__list > li:hover .sub-menu__list
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .sub-menu__list > li:hover .sub-sub-menu__list
    {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .arrow {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu__list {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu__list,
    .sub-menu__list,
    .sub-sub-menu__list {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .menu__list.open,
    .sub-menu__list.open,
    .sub-sub-menu__list.open {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__list">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="menu__link link">First level</a>
                <span class="menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a>
                        <span class="sub-menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu__list">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link link">First level</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="menu__link link">First level</a>
                <span class="menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a>
                        <span class="sub-menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-menu__list">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link link">Third level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu__link link">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Okay i made it nice, if somebody needs - you are welcome.